# Foreach and save filesmultiupload?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have multiupload files form, when is posted i got something like this

```
$_FILES['slike']=Array( 

[name] => Array ( [0] => 64_maska.png [1] => 35proba.jpg ) 
[type] => Array ( [0] => image/png [1] => image/jpeg ) 
[tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /tmp/phpMgwdZD [1] => /tmp/phpzgEGyW ) 
[error] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 )
[size] => Array ( [0] => 30389 [1] => 84375 )
 )
```

Now i want to foreach this array to get something like this

```
foreach ($_FILES['slike'] as $slika)
{

$source=$_FILES['slike']['tmp_name'];
$newimage=$_FILES['slike']['name'];
$path = "uploads/";
move_uploaded_file($source, $path.$newimage)

}
```

I know i have errors in foreach, but dont know how to fix, maybe i have to make two new arrays to accomplish this? I dont know how to foreach different value from multidimensional array :*(

Comment: I don't think you need foreach here based on what you posted.

Comment: Ok, what do i need, if i have so many files info in array :(

Comment: is that your complete $_FILES array or is there more to it ?

Comment: That is complete array, it can only can have more members in each array :)

Comment: can you update your question with output of var_dump($_FILES); and format the output correctly for easy readability ?

Comment: This is print_r($_FILES['slike']), this array can be changed, only adding new members to [name]
[type]
[tmp_name]
[error]
[size]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a for loop :

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['slike']['name']); $i++) {

    $source=$_FILES['slike']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $newimage=$_FILES['slike']['name'][$i];
    $path = "uploads/";
    move_uploaded_file($source, $path.$newimage)
}
```

Comment: I think $i should start with 0 and $i<= should be $i<

Comment: Some small error Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 2

Comment: @Gorostas Have to change `$i<= count` to `$i< count`. Check the update.

Comment: Just please fix, ($i=0; $i< count($_FILES['slike']['name']); $i++) For someone else to see, nice work this works like charm! Txanks

Comment: @Glavić znam matori, ali sve ovo se pravi iz jasona preko javascripta, jedino sam tako uspeo da ga napravim na taj nacin

Comment: @FouadFodail please fix 'name'

Comment: @Gorostas Missed it. Now it is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `for` loop, use `foreach` :

```
$path = "uploads/";
foreach ($_FILES['slike']['name'] as $i => $name) {
    $type = $_FILES['slike']['type'][$i];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['slike']['tmp_name'][$i], $path . $name)
}
```